# работы с одинаковыми классами js

Tags: javascript

Есть множество картинок с одним классом crypt_img, при ховере на которые нужно чтобы показался соответствующий ему блок с классом crypt_text, которых тоже имеется несколько, как это реализовывается в js? Видел пару раз, что с помощью val(), eq() и attr(), но знаний очень мало, чтобы реализовать это и написать код

Answer (score 0):

Вам точно необходимо использовать JS, или возможно просто использовать CSS? Можно более подробно где должен отображаться текстовый блок.

```css
 .photo {
    display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
   }
   .photo:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-title); /* Выводим текст */
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 20%; top: 30%; /* Положение подсказки */
    z-index: 1; /* Отображаем подсказку поверх других элементов */
    background: rgba(255,255,230,0.9); /* Полупрозрачный цвет фона */
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    font-size: 11px; /* Размер текста подсказки */
    padding: 5px 10px; /* Поля */
    border: 1px solid #333; /* Параметры рамки */
   }
```

```html
   <div class="photo" data-title="Это Apple!"><img src="https://infoday.site/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/apple-03.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/k9xwj6

Comment: Вот нужно при наведении на соответствующую криптовалюту, чтобы соответствующая надпись вылазила, у изображений криптовалют одинаковый класс crypt_img, у всплывающих подсказок - crypt_text

Comment: А тот вариант с CSS что я выше написал Вам не подходит? Надо именно JS использовать?